# Does this sentence mean what I intended it to mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparative-constructions

I want to introduce a work of mine, and I wrote:

> 1. "I discovered a proof of a theorem. The proof, **simpler than any existing ones**, was published ..."

to mean,

> 2. "I discovered a proof of a theorem. The proof is simpler than any existing proofs of the theorem, was published ..."

What I am not sure about is the **boldfaced** part. Does it mean what I intended it to mean?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they mean the same thing.

That said, it does read a little awkwardly; personally, I'd change it slightly, to "This proof, simpler than those currently available, was published..."

Also, it might be an idea to note **how** this new proof is simpler. Is it simpler to understand? Simpler to perform? Simpler to teach?

Comment: I'd be partial to "simpler than prior ones"

Comment: The second one needs the word "and" added after the comma so it reads "and was published..."

Answer (score 2):

The bolded version is fine.  The second sentence of your second option is a bit fractured. 
Even aside from Damien's suggested wordsmithing, it should be

> The proof is simpler than any existing proof of the theorem**;** it was published ...

or

> The proof is simpler than any existing proof of the theorem**.**  It was published ...

And (one of my pet peeves): The proof exists. 
It cannot be simpler than itself. 
Therefore, I believe that you should say

> The proof is simpler than any ***other*** existing proof of the theorem ...